# Post JSON data to web API using object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, http

I was able to write the code to perform GET operation from a web API. But, I'm not able to POST. I think the problem is with the JSON object. I'm able to POST if the parameters are sent via URL but I'm unable to do so if it's a JSON Object. Eg: The POST requires me to send ModelID, CustomerID via URL and ReferenceString as a JSON object.

**Data to POST**

> ModelID = 3345
>
> CustomerID =1V34858493
>
> ReferenceID is a JSON string[]
>
> [
>     {
>       "ReferenceId": "a123"
>     }
>   ]

Main

```
 static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       // JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string patientServiceResponse = PostRequest( string.Format("https://url.com/api/{0}/{1}/taskOrders", 3345, "1V34858493"));

        Debug.Write(patientServiceResponse);
    }
```

POST Request

```
private static string PostRequest(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        string sContentType = "application/json";

        JObject oJsonObject = new JObject();

        oJsonObject.Add("ReferenceId", "a123");

        HttpClient oHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var oTaskPostAsync = oHttpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(oJsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));

        //return 
    }
```

Can you please correct me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Debug the application and check what string content you are really posting. Compare it with the one you had to post

Comment: Why are you mixing HttpWebRequest and HttpClient?

Comment: @mason OP is also creating an obsolete serializer instance. Maybe some kind of throttle ;o)

Comment: @mason - I'm sorry, I'm still trying to understand the concept here. Can you please provide a reference guide to post JSON data. I would appreciate it

Comment: Is there a reason why you initialize `JavaScriptSerializer serializer` but never use it?

Comment: You are creating an HttpWebRequest and then doing nothing with it. Then you're posting data using an HttpClient. You need to pick one or the other, don't mix them, and don't create a request and then not send it

Comment: Please add a sample JSON as described by the API documentation with **more than one** reference id. The current description *ReferenceId is a string[]* does not match your JSON sample *[{"ReferenceId":"a123"}]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Mason! I wrote the code to POST the data to the web API using `HttpWebRequest`.

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string patientServiceResponse = PostRequest( string.Format("https://url.com/api/{0}/{1}/taskOrders", 3345, "1V34858493"));

    Debug.Write(patientServiceResponse);
}
```

**POST**

```
private static string PostRequest(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "[  { \"ReferenceId\": \"a123\"  } ]";
            Debug.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        try
        {
            using (var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (httpWebRequest.HaveResponse && response != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response != null)
            {
                using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        result = error;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

POST function will look like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{modelId}/{customerId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(string modelId, string customerId, REFDto referenceId)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Create a DTO class for reference Id

```
public class REFDto
{
    public string referenceId { get; set; }
}
```

API Client call :

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var modelId = "3345";
            var customerId = "1V34858493";
            var url = $"https://url.com/api/{modelId}/{customerId}/taskOrders";
            JObject oJsonObject = new JObject();
            oJsonObject.Add("referenceId", "ref123");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(oJsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
```

Comment: I wasn't able to comment below.  It is not a good idea to put too much inside the catch block.  What if there is another exception inside it?